# Instantaneous Frequency variation

Tags: sampling

I am looking for a method to calculate the instantaneous pitch variation within a speech signal for time-warping application. Sample by sample frequency variation knowledge within a frame will give more accurate output in time-warping.

Till now, I read about a method based on Teager's energy operator. Please suggest me some other methods for the same.

Comment: "Instantaneous frequency" only has meaning for limited classes of signals.  Humans do not track speech pitch instantaneously or "sample by sample", but rather over some very small number of pitch periods.  There is a rich literature on pitch estimators with test results, too many to suggest.

Comment: @hotpow2 If we look over the spectrogram of speech signal, it can easily be identified that frequencies are slowly varying wrt time. I am here trying to know the instantaneous change in  frequency of any single-frequency component(after bandpass filtered that particular frequency region) within a speech signal.